# Lightbox2 pageload trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox2

How can I trigger a lightbox2 body on load. I need a popup when user enters a site.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Automagically load Lightbox on Page Load - by Bramus! (http://www.bram.us/)
        // Code modded from http://www.huddletogether.com/forum/comments.php?DiscussionID=1269&page=1#Item_0
        function autoFireLightbox() {
            //Check if location.hash matches a lightbox-anchor. If so, trigger popup of image.
            setTimeout(function() {
                if(document.location.hash && $(document.location.hash.substr(1)).rel.indexOf('lightbox')!=-1) {
                    myLightbox.start($(document.location.hash.substr(1)));
                }},
                250
            );
        }
        Event.observe(window, 'load', autoFireLightbox, false);
</script>
```

Comment: Where are you getting `myLightbox` from?

Answer (score 0):

Or something like this:

```
$(function(){
     // Link to open
     $("#link").click();
});
```

You do need to initialize the fancybox first before you can open the fancybox.

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Y554b/1/

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple link, that includes "/lightbox2" at the end of url, and "rel" attribute.

```
<a id='popup' href="url/lightbox2" rel="lightframe">&nbsp;</a>
```

And js something like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function() {
  $('#popup').trigger('click');
});
</script>
```

To show it once, or for a while I use jQuery.cookie :)